# ¿Cómo combinar N ficheros CSV en uno omitiendo las columnas (excepto del primero)?

Tags: php, php7

Tengo varios csv:

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
...
n.csv
```

Todos tienen la misma estructura:

```
col1, col2, col3, ..., coln
valor, valor, valor, ..., valor
```

Y tengo la siguiente función:

```
function unir(array $files, $result) {
    if(!is_array($files)) {
        throw new Exception('`$files` debe ser un array');
    }

    $wH = fopen($result, "w+");

    foreach($files as $file) {
        $fh = fopen($file, "r");
        while(!feof($fh)) {
            fwrite($wH, fgets($fh));
        }
        fclose($fh);
        unset($fh);
        fwrite($wH, "\n");
    }
    fclose($wH);
    unset($wH);
}
```

El problema es que me une col1, col2, col3, ..., coln de 2.csv, 3.csv ..., n.csv, sólo me interesa la columna de 1.csv.

Answer (score 1):

La función [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php) según la documentación:

> Obtiene una línea desde el puntero a un fichero.
> [...] La lectura termina cuando se han leído `length - 1` bytes, o una nueva línea (la cual está incluida en el valor de retorno), o un EOF (lo que suceda primero). Si no se especifica una longitud, se seguirá leyendo desde el flujo hasta que alcance el final de la línea.

Es decir, si omitimos el parámetro `length` lee de a una línea del archivo.

Entonces, si identificamos el número de archivos recorridos y las líneas leidas en cada uno podemos evitar escribir la primer línea para los archivos que no sean el primero.

#### Ejemplo:

```php
function unir(array $files, $result)
{
    if (!is_array($files)) {
        throw new Exception('`$files` debe ser un array');
    }

    $wH = fopen($result, "w+");

    // $fileIdx indice del archivo en el arreglo
    foreach ($files as $fileIdx => $file) {

        $fh = fopen($file, "r");
        // $lineNum contador de lineas leidas del archivo
        $lineNum = 0;
        while (!feof($fh)) {

            $line = fgets($fh);
            $lineNum++;

            // Si NO es el primer archivo y SI es la primer linea
            if ($fileIdx > 0 && $lineNum === 1) continue;
            // Escribimos la linea leída
            fwrite($wH, $line);
        }
        fclose($fh);
        unset($fh);
        fwrite($wH, "\n");
    }
    fclose($wH);
    unset($wH);
}
```